# Passing a signed char array to function expecting const char pointer results in garbled array value

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, char, parameter-passing

I cant seem to wrap my head around what is happening here:

I have a function that calculates the difference between two dates in seconds. Then it gets bitshifted around to produce some output:

```
void GetUTC(unsigned char buffer[5])
{
    struct tm str_time;
    time_t start;
    time_t current = time(NULL);
    str_time.tm_year = 2010 - 1900;
    str_time.tm_mon = 1;
    str_time.tm_mday = 1;
    str_time.tm_hour = 0;
    str_time.tm_min = 0;
    str_time.tm_sec = 0;
    str_time.tm_isdst = 0;
    start = mktime(&str_time);

    printf("%s\n",ctime(&start));
    printf("%s\n\n",ctime(&current));

    uint32_t someInt = difftime(current,start);
    buffer[0] = 2;
    buffer[1] = (someInt & 0xff);
    someInt = someInt >> 8;
    buffer[2] = (someInt & 0xff);
    someInt = someInt >> 8;
    buffer[3] = someInt;
    someInt = someInt >> 8;
    buffer[4] = (10 & 0xff);
}
```

I feed it this array:

```
    unsigned char toWrite[5];
```

Then call it

```
    GetUTC(toWrite);
```

All goes well. Now I have a function I am trying to feed the new array into, which takes these parameters:

```
void gatt_write_attribute(GDBusProxy *proxy, const char *arg)
```

And I call it with:

```
gatt_write_attribute(someProxy, toWrite);
```

However the array I passed to the function `gatt_write_attribute` shows that it's the jumbled garbage: `$2\20023\n23` instead of my expected value of toWrite. (numbers differ since it has to do with time):

```
[0]: 2
[1]: 23
[2]: 54
[3]: 128
[4]: 10
```

I tried adding a terminating `\0` to the end of `toWrite`, but it did not change anything. I tried casting it to a `const char` pointer and that didn't work either.

I feel like I'm missing a very simple detail. Could someone explain why I cant pass this char array to the `gatt_write_attribute` function?

Comment: It's difficult to see where the problem could be. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You know that you're analyzing for February 1st 2010, don't you?  Month numbers start at 0 for January.

Comment: What *is* the expected output, then? Are we supposed to know by magic what a hidden function does?

Comment: Indeed, I corrected that in my own code right after but forgot to change it here. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Your function adds control-B (`2`) followed by 4 arbitrary byte values in the range 0x00..0xFF to the buffer.  Unless the function you call expects a fixed size not-necessarily-null-terminated buffer, it will mishandle the data when there isn't a null byte in it, and will mishandle the data when there is a null byte in the middle of it. What value are you expecting your function to produce? Have you printed what it does produce to make sure you get what you expect? At the moment, the problem seems to be with your expectations rather than the code. Or, your code doesn't implement what you need.

Comment: If i understand correctly everything is fine before the call to `gatt_write_attribute` and after the call the data in `ToWrite` is garbled? Must be some accidental memory overwriting somewhere since `gatt_write_attribute` promises not to alter the data. (const)

Comment: The data is garbled as soon as I pass it to gatt_write_attribute. Breaking into the script I found the value of toWrite is garbled.

Comment: It appears you expect  code `buffer[4] = (10 & 0xff);` to generate `[4]: 172`.  Why do you not expect `[4]: 10`?

Comment: @chux I typed some random values, I'm sorry!

Comment: The implementation of `gatt_write_attribute` that I found by googling should not to return any output into that array. The array should be used as input of attributes. The function also modifies that array by casting it to `(char*)` and using `strsep`. Post real function `gatt_write_attribute` that you are using.

Comment: It doesnt return any output into that array. I am breaking inside that function to check the value of toWrite, which is garbled, that's what the question is about. The implementation of `gatt_write_attribute` is not important here.

Comment: by googling i found that gatt_write_attribute is related to bluez library, but i didn't found the API, can you send us the API documentation?

Comment: Output is not garbage  `$2\20023\n23` --> `'\2'`, `'\200'` , `'2'`, `'3'`, `'\n'` (which is 10), and the rest is beyond the array.  I suspect there is no problem, just a misunderstanding of `$2\20023\n23`

Comment: @Zimano your debugger is probably trying to display the thing being pointed to as an array of characters. You need to display it as an array of numbers.

Comment: @Zimano - Note that you are passing the *actual parameter* `toWrite` to `GetUTC`, within which it becomes the *formal parameter* `buffer`. `GetUTC` should only refer to `buffer`, never to `toWrite`. `toWrite` must be global, or the compiler would have complained. However, I don't think this would cause the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) and [Chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) in the comments to my original question, I was indeed being silly and was not realizing that my debugger was displaying the thing being pointed to as an array of characters instead of numbers. This is what caused the garbled values.

I should have probably allowed myself a bit more sleep in-between work hours.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the array to the first function as a pointer. Otherwise it just gets copied to the stack and the function writes to the new copy. The garbage is probably there because it has not been initialised.

Comment: No, arrays are passed by reference. The array is already being passed as a pointer, and the array declared in the function prototype isn't really an array as C changes it to a pointer declaration automatically.